# Linux 7zip destination folder?

Tags: 7z

I want to zip with 7zip a folder to specific destination. There is in manual a guide to use `-o{folder}` but how does it really work?

Example:

```
7z a -t7z backup1 /home/example/folder -o/home/backups/folder1
```

How to use that `-o` ? Destination folder exists.

Answer (score 4):

As per [the manual](http://www.scottklement.com/p7zip/MANUAL/switches/output_dir.htm), the `-o` (set Output directory) switch

> Specifies a destination directory where files are to be extracted.
>   This switch can be used only with extraction commands.

When archiving you can simply do something like this:

```sh
7z a /path/to/archives/archive.7z /path/to/source
```

Comment: Output directory only applies to unpacking/decompression.

Comment: @tansy that already exists into the answer: "This switch can be used only with extraction commands."